# Defining storable instance for union data types

Tags: haskell, vector, storable

How do you define the [storable vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/latest/doc/html/Data-Vector-Storable.html) instance for a data type like below (composed from GHC primitive types):

```
data Atoms =  I GHC.Int.Int32|S GHC.Int.Int16 -- define a union data type
```

I checked this [storable tutorial](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell%3a_A_Vector_Tutorial#Storing_your_own_types_in_Storable_vectors) but it works only for vectors of same types, not union like above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to encode which constructor you used to instantiate the type somehow.

You can for example add a byte that specifies the index of the constructor that was used. This means that the values above could be stored like this:

```
Haskell    Binary
I 3     -> 00 00 00 00 03
S 4     -> 01 00 04 XX XX
              ^ Data
           ^ Constructor index
XX = unused byte
```

Then, when you want to deserialize a value from a byte string, you peek the first byte, see which index it is, and choose the constructor to use (and what to peek off next) based on that.

Comment: @Chris: Seriously? I was under the impression that unions in C merely share the same memory. It's the programmer's responsibility to know what "instance" of a union to use. Many programmers do this manually using tagging technique like the one described in this answer.

Comment: Honestly, I think that union data types *aren't* a natural fit for Storable at all.  I would strongly urge you to just use normal boxed vectors.